# I am learning web scraping in R , facing the error after running the code : Error

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am learning web scraping in R, trying to scrape questions page on math stack exchange, with the help of following code :

Objective of the following code is to gather all the links of the questions and then scrape the accepted solution of the questions. However while I run the code I got the error at the end :

Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404.

```
library(rvest)

link <- "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integration"
url <- read_html(link) 
page <- url %>%   html_nodes(".question-hyperlink")  %>%  html_text()

questions_link <- url %>%   html_nodes(".question-hyperlink") %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>% paste("https://math.stackexchange.com", .,sep = "")


get_answer = function(answer_link){
    answer_page <- read_html(answer_link)
  solution = answer_page %>% html_nodes(".accepted-answer") %>% html_text() 
  return(solution)
}

solution_accepted <- sapply(questions_link, FUN = get_answer)
```

Can you please help on this , will be of great help. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in `questions_link` there are other links extracted which are not questions of that forum. It is extracting the links from the "Hot Network Questions" on the right.

[image]

Filter the links further to get only the questions from the forum.

```
library(rvest)

questions_link <- url %>%   
  html_nodes("h3 a.question-hyperlink") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>% 
  paste0("https://math.stackexchange.com", .)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, can you please also take a look on this : 
link <- "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integration"
url <- read_html(link) 

url

page <- url %>%   html_nodes(".question-hyperlink")  %>%  html_text()
making dataframe of : page and solution_accepted in the above code, is showing some error, thanks once again for your help..